# how to use javax.persistence.Query.executeUpdate() and org.hibernate.session.update() in same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa-2.0, jpa

I have an object form class x that I want to update it's properties by session.update() and also a list of objects from class x too that I want to update a property in them using query.executeUpdate() in same transaction. after commit the transaction server output log show this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [com.net.models.hibernate.OrganizationStructure#1]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3241)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3090)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3491)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:600)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
... 45 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 16
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:3963)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNullCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4596)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNull(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4578)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setNull(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1285)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setNull(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:462)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:61)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2729)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3168)
... 53 more

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using some kind of wrong Dialect or configuration. The error suggests that Hibernate tries to bind a `null` for the JDBC type code `16` which is for Boolean, but Oracle does not support that. Usually, booleans are modeled as char(1) or numeric(1) on Oracle with Hibernate. You could try to explicitly specify the type by adding `@Type(type = "yes_no")`, `@Type(type = "true_false")` or `@Type(type = "numeric_boolean")` to the boolean attributes, but this should normally work out of the box, so please check your configuration.